# Need REGEX Help to clean hacked script

Tags: php, regex

My site is getting hacked. It add some script on my file at the first line of all my php file. I want to get remove that script using Netbeans search and replace with **REGEX** options.

It seems the hack script has same pattern on it

```
<?php /**/ eval(base64_decode("[SomeRandomString]"])); ?>
```

Can you please give me REGEX pattern to remove the string above?

Here is the example of my hacked full script http://ideone.com/6ltMf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this matches your short example and the one you pasted:

```
$pattern = '~^\<\?php\s?\/\*\*\/\seval\(base64\_decode\(\".*?\)\)\;\s?\?\>~'
// You might need to incorporate the multi-line option at the end of the pattern
```

Hindsight is 20/20: In the future you should consider using a versioning system to quickly reset all the altered files.

Comment: can you explain what the meaning of `~` at the first and the end of the string?

Comment: `~` Are pattern delimiters required by PHP's regex engine. They denote the beginning and end of the pattern. The character itself is arbitrary - a lot of people use `/` (PHP uses `/` in the examples for `preg_match()` http://php.net/preg_match). I prefer a character that doesn't exist in the pattern to help with readability (as if regex patterns have any hope of being readable :p).

Comment: Testing and tried with removing `~` char, i didn't know maybe that char only work in php, but here i use Netbeans replace feature. Work like charm. Thank you. :D

Comment: Doh, sorry. I forgot you were using the pattern in Netbeans and not the PHP regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just manually remove it?  If you have too many files to do so, then automation sounds good.  Since it's decoding the string and evaluating it as a PHP expression then it should be the same on every file if it's really automating itself.  Just copy the string exactly, and tell your script to look for that exact string in all your .php files.  I believe it's something like

```
"eval(base64_decode("aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdvYl9zdGFydC.......));"
```

The special characters are: [\^$.|?*+(), and if you want to search for them you need to precede them with a "\" in order for the matching to properly work, so your RE becomes:

```
"eval\(base64_decode\("aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdvYl9zdGFydC.......\)\);"
```

You're going to need to check that the string doesn't contain any more special characters.  Also you may just want to reinstall your version of PHP depending on what this virus does, as it, but you should just google "eval base64_decode", that's what I found forum posts about the virus with.